# Second drop down select list shows as text only

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a form in HTML5 but I'm having a problem with drop down list menus. The Second drop down list in my form always displays text only. I've even copy and pasted the exact same form twice in a row and the first and third ones work but the second just shows a list of text.

Ex:

```
<form>
    <p>
    <label for="x">Sample Drop Down</label>
    <select type="list" name="sample">
    <option>-----Select One-----</option>
        <option value="s1">Sample 1</option>
        <option value="s2">Sample 2</option>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="y">Sample Drop Down 2</label>
    <select type="list" name="sample2">
    <option>-----Select One-----</option>
        <option value="s3">Sample 3</option>
        <option value="s4">Sample 4</option>
    </p>
</form>
```

Any ideas what it could be? I'm sorry if this is something simple, but I'm just learning and couldn't find any examples of similar problems online.

Comment: after the <option></option> tags you should close the <select> tags </select>

Comment: You can use an [HTML Validator](https://html5.validator.nu/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the closing select tags.

```
<form>
    <p>
    <label for="x">Sample Drop Down</label>
    <select type="list" name="sample">
    <option>-----Select One-----</option>
        <option value="s1">Sample 1</option>
        <option value="s2">Sample 2</option>
</select>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="y">Sample Drop Down 2</label>
    <select type="list" name="sample2">
    <option>-----Select One-----</option>
        <option value="s3">Sample 3</option>
        <option value="s4">Sample 4</option>
</select>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you!  For some reason i thought the select tag didn't need to be closed, I even remember thinking it was weird when the tutorial I was watching didn't close out the tag.

Answer (score 2):

after the  tags you should close the  tags

```
<form>
    <p>
    <label for="x">Sample Drop Down</label>
    <select type="list" name="sample">
    <option>-----Select One-----</option>
        <option value="s1">Sample 1</option>
        <option value="s2">Sample 2</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="y">Sample Drop Down 2</label>
    <select type="list" name="sample2">
    <option>-----Select One-----</option>
        <option value="s3">Sample 3</option>
        <option value="s4">Sample 4</option>
    </select>
    </p>
</form>
```